Intersection of two quadrics is elliptic curve
I am currently studying Jacobi intersection models of elliptic curves, and so far I have found that whenever you have a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ we have an embedding of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ into $\mathbb{P}^3$ via the Jacobi theta functions, the resulting image being an intersection of twoquadrics, i.e. the intersection of $x^2 + y^2=1, k^2x^2 + z^2 = 1$. My question is, given two quadrics of this form, how do I reverse this map, i.e. how can I show that every intersection of this form corresponds to a unique (up to hometheticity) lattice, and subsequently an ellitpic curve over the complex numbers? I realise this must have something to do with the modulus $k^2$ over here, but I'm a little bit confused.

From here you can write the intersection in Edwards form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve) and there should be formulas in the literature showing how to convert to Weierstrass form and compute the $j$-invariant and so forth.
